# I want remove the data from specific column in dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

[INPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h47Gk.jpg)

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49t8z.jpg)
I want to remove the last paranthesis in entire column

Raw input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'no':[1,2,3,4], 'Name':['Mumbai SUPPLY (CO)  (fO, 10)','Chennai GROUP  (LLC) THE  (PO, 330)','Nagpur (Bi) SUPPLY (LO, 90)','NAGPUR (C) MD  (lO, P0)']})
```

Comment: I want askers to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ask clear questions ;)

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far with code markdown so others can extend that with an answer.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Try to explain your question a bit more